# How To make speech visualizer for speech recognition without using mediaDevices.getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, android, speech-recognition, visualizer

Using JavaScript and speech recognition API Can I build a visualizer to reflect user speech like the one in the link below, without using getUserMedia.

The reason of my request because getUserMedia and speechrecognition are not working simultaneously on mobile devices like Samsung/Android.

Using getUserMedia example
https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/voice-change-o-matic/

I don't know where to start, but I think onresult event of speechrecognition should be used to implement such effect.